# Microphone keeps breaking up in Steam

Tags: microphone, steam

I've just tried using my microphone with Steam (both the back and front microphone ports) and it constantly breaks up... my friend said he coudln't hear me properly, and having done the test through the Steam settings he's not wrong - it breaks up during every sentence, and sometimes doesn't work at all.

Bizarrely though, when I test the microphone in Windows it works flawlessly, using both the voice recorder, and testing in the microphone properties

Any ideas why it would only break up in Steam please? :(

Thanks

Comment: We would need to know a little more specific information about the hardware in order to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting a QoS priority for in your router? The issue could be that you have a slow network connection (or something slowing down your network connection). Quality of Service (QoS) can allow specific IP Addresses, MAC Addresses or services to take priority when delegating bandwidth. The reason why it may work find on Windows and not on your STEAM client could be that there is no network traffic required for local recording/monitoring of the microphone whereas STEAM Voice Chat requires the audio to be sent over the net.

[Source](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711)

```
Steamworks P2P Networking and Steam Voice Chat
UDP 3478 (Outbound)
UDP 4379 (Outbound)
UDP 4380 (Outbound)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, it does it locally through Steam though when I test which AFAIK doesn't rely on the network